# How do I edit wp_head and/or functions.php to remove rss-feed which isnt used and dont validate?

Tags: functions, rss, validation, wp-head

When using w3.org's validation tool Unicorn I get the following error/warning:

URI: http://energyshop.se/hem/feed/ 
This feed does not validate.

After looking into my source its there crystal clear in the `<head>:
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="energyshop.se &raquo; Hem kommentarsflöde" href="http://energyshop.se/hem/feed/" />`

Now, how do I remove this feed since I dont use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the file

```
/wp-includes/default-filters.php
```

we can find these two lines in there

```
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links',                      2     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links_extra',                3     );
```

so if we want to remove these actions, we can do it with these two lines in `functions.php`:

```
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links',2);
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links_extra',3);
```

So the feed links will be removed from the `<head>` tag.

**ps:** In this file you will also find:

```
add_action( 'do_feed_rdf',                'do_feed_rdf',                             10, 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss',                'do_feed_rss',                             10, 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2',               'do_feed_rss2',                            10, 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_atom',               'do_feed_atom',                            10, 1 );
```

If you want to disable the feeds, you can remove these hooks in a similar way with:

```
remove_action( 'do_feed_rdf', 'do_feed_rdf', 10, 1 );
remove_action( 'do_feed_rss', 'do_feed_rss', 10, 1 );
remove_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'do_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );
remove_action( 'do_feed_atom', 'do_feed_atom', 10, 1 );
```

but then you will get this message when you visit the feed links

[image]

You might consider making url rewrites for the feed links or make a custom feed template, to get rid of this message.

Comment: Does the links has to be there because of how Wordpress is structured? And if I were to use remove_action('wp_head','feed_links',2);
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links_extra',3); that would probably solve it but does that solution also generate that error because its not according to the template anymore? And if so, the best way would be to redirect it to just energyshop.se instead and keep it in the background without any real function?

Comment: Your feed does not validate because the `<lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>` is empty. You can remove the feed from the `<head>` tag and then you can check this to fix the empty `lastBuildDate`:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/custom-post-types-rss-lastbuilddate-issue

Comment: I tried it and it works pretty good! Now on the Unicorn test I dont get a red warning kind of message anymore, but instead a blue Information warning: "It looks like this is a web page, not a feed.
I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn't find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate." Since it isnt really an error I could just ignore it, but are there a way to get rid of this one? I know it doesnt change much but I like to get to know how to fix these kind of things for the future.I used the remove_action and the fix from the link you gave into functions.php

Comment: great, maybe you can just fix the empty lastBuildDate and leave the feed link in the header tag, if you don't want this w3 notice. A missing feed link should not change if your site is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

The third params are also required, without them it didn't work for me

```
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links',2);
remove_action('wp_head','feed_links_extra',3);
```